# kibana filter by absent substring

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How to make such kind of requests for kibana?

```
where field does not contain substring
```

It is easy to create filters like `field: substring`. Neither `not "substring"` or `field: not(substring)` or `field: not(*substring*)` work

Answer (score 75):

To add to @gayavat's answer (which has put me on the right track), here is a real-life example:

```
NOT message:(view.html)
```

This is assuming I've got a filed "message", which is standard for Java logs.
Or, you can combine it with other criteria:

```
pension AND NOT message:(view.html)
```

That will search for all occurrences of "pension", excluding those appearing together with the "view.html"

Answer (score 20):

`-field: "tracker"` works! Unfortunately, I did not find it in docs but only here http://logs101.com/how-to-overcome-the-missing-editable-filters-feature-in-kibana-4/

Comment: For what it's worth, that information can be found in the official docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators)